# c# function inaccessible due to protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently following a tutorial on YouTube on how to make a maze game in Unity with c# scripts. During part of the tutorial, the uploader is using a function from the "GameManager" script and calling it in the "PlayerMovement" script. in the video everything works fine, but when I try to implement it, it gives me "CS0122  'GameManager.CompleteLevel()' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

here are some code snippets to help visualize my problem:

"PlayerMovement"

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Goal")
        GameManager.CompleteLevel();
}
```

"GameManager"

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int currentScore;
    public static int highScore;

    public static int currentLevel =0;
    public static int unlockedLevel;

    void CompleteLevel()
    {
        currentLevel++;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentLevel);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: the error is happening on the PlayerMovement side when it is trying to call GameManager.CompleteLevel();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoul mark a method with public modifier

```
public void CompleteLevel()
```

Without modifier it is private (for use in the class only)

Comment: thank you this got rid of the CS0122 error.
i was hit with another error but changing it to public static void seemed to fix it

Comment: @TylerStMartin I think you should get an understanding of what static and object/member methods are. It is important to get this understanding, or you will run into all sorts of program flow issues later.